# What to change when ico has been ended and public sale will be started

Tags: solidity, ico, uniswap

I want to start an ico on the ERC20 network. The ico will be available for three months for example.
For that I have to write a smart contract. That is clear to me.

It is only not clear to me what happens when the ico has ended and then a couple of months later I want to sell the token completely publicly (for example, the coin can be sold on uniswap but also on an exchange). Do I have to write a new smart contract? Because ones you have deployed a smart contract, it can not be changed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trading pair for your token on [SushiSwap](https://sushi.com/) which is a decentralised exchange that can trade any ERC-20 token.

To have a market, you need to provide liquidity on both buy and sell side and have somebody to act as a market maker. They then buy your token from you.

(Assuming anybody is willing to buy.)